# Wordpress page listing adding control to list items

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

So basically i have an Main Parent page with sub-category pages where each sub-category page has child pages and using the code provides, it works perfectly fine displaying each parent with its children.

I would like to know can have full control over the listing, because for only the parent tabs, i would like to add an image using ACF (advance custom fields) , meaning if that parent page in the CMS has a logo(`$tab_logo = get_field('parent_tab_logo');`) add it to the listing with the parent name.

**Code:**

```
<?php

// find parent of current page
if ($post->post_parent) {

    $ancestors = get_post_ancestors($post->ID);
    $parent = $ancestors[count($ancestors) - 1];

    //Display Parent post Title
    $parent_post_id = $parent;
    $parent_post = get_post($parent_post_id);
    $parent_post_title = $parent_post->post_title;

} else {
    $parent = $post->ID;
}

$children = wp_list_pages("sort_order=asc&title_li=&child_of=" . $parent . "&echo=0");

if ($children) { ?>
   <div id="side" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">

        <h4><?php echo $parent_post_title; ?></h4>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                  <ul id="side-navi" class="list-unstyled mb-0 ">

                      <?php echo $children; ?>

                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>

    </div>

<?php } ?>
```

**Current outcome:** (example)

- Main Parent PAGE
- Parent-1 (child of Main Parent PAGE)
- child1 (child of Parent-1)
- child2 (child of Parent-1)
- Parent-2 (child of Main Parent PAGE)
- child1 (child of Parent-2)
- child2 (child of Parent-2)

**Expected outcome:** (example)

- Main Parent PAGE
- Parent-1 (IMAGE from this page using acf = `$tab_logo = get_field('parent_tab_logo');`)
- child1
- child2
- Parent-2 (IMAGE from this page using acf = `$tab_logo = get_field('parent_tab_logo');`)
- child1
- child2

Comment: What seems to be the problem then? You have full control over the list and the logo

Comment: Using ACF i dont want to add the images using background image, i want the user to add the image via CMS using ACF, but using `<?php echo $children; ?>` i cant say example `<li>$parent <img class="img-fluid" src="<?php if($tab_logo ){ echo tab_logo;  ?>"> </li>`, which is what im trying to achieve. Make sense?

Comment: you can provide `get_field()` with an ID  - which you have for the parent -  `$tab_logo = get_field('parent_tab_logo', $parent_post_id);`

Answer (score 0):

This should be as simple as what the ACF docs say.

You need to get the field when you check for a parent then display the field in the relevant section, passing the post id might also save you some headaches so it only targets your parent items.

Hope this helps.

```
<?php 

$parent_image = get_field('image', $post_id);

if( !empty($parent_image) ): ?>

<img src="<?php echo $parent_image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $parent_image['alt']; ?>" />

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thing is im trying to target the parents within `<?php echo $children; ?>` which consist of sub-parent and child's of sub-parent pages. Also update my question to for you to see that  `<?php echo $children; ?>` is child pages of `<?php echo $parent_post_title; ?>`, hope you can help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like the below, where you pass the parents post id into the get_field() function. Depending on how you have set up the image in ACF, you may need to update how you are pulling out the image.

```
<?php

// find parent of current page
if ($post->post_parent) {

  $ancestors = get_post_ancestors($post->ID);
  $parent = $ancestors[count($ancestors) - 1];

  //Display Parent post Title
  $parent_post_id = $parent;
  $parent_post = get_post($parent_post_id);
  $parent_post_title = $parent_post->post_title;
  $parent_image = get_field('parent_tab_logo', $parent_post_id);

} else {
  $parent = $post->ID;
}

$children = wp_list_pages("sort_order=asc&title_li=&child_of=" . $parent . "&echo=0");

if ($children) { 
  ?>
  <div id="side" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">

    <h4><?php echo $parent_post_title; ?></h4>
    <?php
      if( !empty($parent_image) ){
      ?>
      <img src="<?php echo $parent_image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $parent_image['alt']; ?>" />
      <?php
      } 
    ?>


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <ul id="side-navi" class="list-unstyled mb-0 ">
          <?php echo $children; ?>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Hi man il need to amend my question after seeing your anwser i realized i missed something, which is all this `<?php echo $children; ?>` has a main category page example Stay , and then sub categories pages, where the subcategories pages has children, im trying to siplay image from the subcategories pages. ill explain better in question, ill quickly amend , but thanks for help.

Comment: I'm really sorry but I am struggling to understand your question :/ One thing to note, you may run into a undefined index where you echo $parent_post_title if no parent is found. Would be worth adding a conditional check around this?

Comment: cool ill add the conditional check, Also update my question , look at the current outcome and expected outcome to see where the image comes from. Hope it helps you understand ;/